# How to define an OSGI/Eclipse plugin with binary components for multiple platforms

Tags: eclipse, osgi, native-code, tycho, osgi-fragment

I created an Eclipse plugin and there is a native binary needed to support its functionality. I have the native code ready for Win and Mac. The invocation of the native code is different for each platform, so there is also some plugin code related to the native code. (In fact the native code is JNA code, so very different indeed.) Currently I have an extension point and each native support plugin contributes there. So, as soon as a native support is here, the main plugin works. Also I have a test fragment for each of the native support plugins to unit test functionality.

1. How should I set the plugin(s) up, so that everybody get's the right plugin when downloading from update site or p2 repo? (I noticed that for example SWT uses fragments for the native code, so is this the way to go?)

**Edit**: After converting the plugins to fragments as indicated by the answer, what should I do with the unit test fragments of these plugins? Fragments of fragments are not possible.

1. How can I set this up in Tycho, so that Tycho build runs the test suitable for the current platform and ignores the other platform.

**Edit**: I have Mac and Windows native code, two fragments and therefore two environments in the pom. But then Tycho complains "plugin x cannot be installed in this environment because its filter is not applicable", of course not, only one of Win/Mac can be active at any certain time. Can Tycho figure out this itself or do I need os dependant Maven profiles?

Comment: Yes, that is the way to go.  What's in the fragment will be added to the plug-ins classpath at runtime, allowing you to talk to the correct plug-in code as well as load the correct native library.

Comment: I know but I will have several fragments then, one for Windows, one for Mac. How to configure this into features and how to define the pom for that in Tycho, that is the question.

Comment: Are the platform tests the same or different for each platform? Do you need to access resources only available in a fragment? In both cases you probably need a fragment from the main bundle, but you may need to tweak classpath settings similar to http://dev.eclipse.org/mhonarc/lists/tycho-dev/msg00122.html

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you will need to package the native bundles into plug-in fragments. Each fragment should specify the platform filter to ensure only one fragment is valid per platform. For example on Windows 64 bit you need to specify os=win32, ws=win32 arch=x86_64.

If your fragments are part of a feature, you should also specify the platform filter in the feature definition.

Under Tycho, you need to specify all your supported platform filter combinations under the [environments](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Tycho/Reference_Card#Target_runtime_environment) section of target platform configuration in your pom file.

Tycho always runs tests under the current platform. Add your fragments to your test runtime - see [here](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Tycho/Packaging_Types#eclipse-test-plugin) on adding dependencies to the tycho test runtime. Tycho often needs help in identifying fragments to add to the test runtime.

Comment: Thank you. I changed my plugins to fragments and supplied platform filters in fragments, feature and Tycho environment. Unfortunately I am not done here. See follow-up questions in main question.